# what is called before onCreate in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Activity Life Cycle - difference between onPause() and OnStop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-difference-between-onpause-and-onstop)

What is called before onCreate in android? So that when I click a tab, I can show a loading screen or some functionality before I actually render my next screen.

Comment: Check this answer it may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/265167

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`onCreate` is the first method to be called from activity ...You can show ur loading screen be setting the proper view in your oncreate method.....

check this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html